# Can someone please explain this block of code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

```
class PortfolioHomeCubit extends Cubit<PortfolioHomeState> {
  PortfolioHomeCubit() : super(PortfolioHomeState());
  final apiService = ApiService();
  Future<void> _onFetchContent() async {
    final cache = apiService.cache;
    final homeContent = cache.portfolioHomeContent;
    emit(state.copyWith(portfolioHomeContent: homeContent));
    final response = await apiService.getData();
    final content = response.portfolioHomeContent;
    emit(state.copyWith(portfolioHomeContent: content));
  }
}
final portfolioHomeContentProvider =
    BlocProvider<PortfolioHomeCubit, PortfolioHomeState>(
  ((ref) => PortfolioHomeCubit().._onFetchContent()),
);
```

This code works just fine but I am confused. If the **_onfetch** function retrieves cached data from the **ApiService** object why do fire another API request? Is it because the cache can be null? and why will it be null when an api request is already fired in the **ApiService** and saved to the cache variable?

Just incase, this is [river_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/riverbloc)

Answer (score 0):

It fetches data both from cache and API server , and then with another function that will check if the cache is null and the internet is not available , it will return a warning in the screen with no internet error .